# Deploying Play Framework (needing a SparkContext) on cluster

Tags: deployment, playframework, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, typesafe-activator

We are deploying to a Cluster a Play! Framework (version 2.3) app that runs jobs needing a SparkContext (e.g : search in Hbase, or WordCount). Our cluster is a Yarn cluster.
To start our app we execute the command line :

```
activator run
```

(after compiling and packaging)

We are experimenting some issues with the SparkContext configuration, we use this configuration :

```
new SparkConf(false)
     .setMaster("yarn-cluster")
     .setAppName("MyApp")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
```

When we call a route that calls a job using the SparkContext we and up with this error :

```
[RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError]
```

or this one (when we reload):

```
[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class mypackage.MyClass$]
```

To test our code we changed the the parameter setMaster to

```
.setMaster("local[4]")
```

And it worked well. But of course our code is not distributed and we do not use the Spark capabilities of distributing our code (e.g : RDD).

Is running our App with the spark submit command a solution? If it is how can this be done ?

We would rather still use the activator command.

Comment: Please refer the following thread on stackoverflow.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728640/add-yarn-cluster-configuration-to-spark-application