# Add Yarn cluster configuration to Spark application

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to use spark on yarn in a scala sbt application instead of using `spark-submit` directly.

I already have a remote yarn cluster running and I can connect to the yarn cluster run spark jobs in SparkR. But when I try to do similar thing in a scala application it couldn't load my environment variables to yarn configurations and instead use default yarn address and port.

The sbt application is just a simple object:

```
object simpleSparkApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("simpleSparkApp")
      .setMaster("yarn-client")
      .set("SPARK_HOME", "/opt/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6")
      .set("HADOOP_HOME", "/opt/hadoop-2.6.0")
      .set("HADOOP_CONF_DIR", "/opt/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  }
}
```

When I run this application in Intellij IDEA the log says:

```
15/11/15 18:46:05 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/11/15 18:46:06 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
15/11/15 18:46:07 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
...
```

It seems the environment is not added correctly because `0.0.0.0` is not the ip of remote yarn resource manager node and my `spark-env.sh` has:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/ibm-java-x86_64-80"
export HADOOP_HOME="/opt/hadoop-2.6.0"
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop"
export SPARK_MASTER_IP="master"
```

and my `yarn-site.xml` has:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>master</value>
</property>
```

How can I correctly add environment variables of Yarn cluster configuration to this sbt Spark application?

Extra information:

My system is Ubuntu14.04 and the SparkR code that can connect to the yarn cluster looks like this:

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME = "/opt/hadoop-2.6.0")
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/opt/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))
library(SparkR)
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "yarn-client")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These days, there's no out of the box solution to avoid the spark-submit usage for Yarn mode.

**Spark-submit** : to run the job, spark-submit run the **org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client** code on the configured environment (or not configured as in your case). Here's the Client which does task submission: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/Client.scala

What the solution though?

1. There was an option to override the Client behavior as could be found here http://blog.sequenceiq.com/blog/2014/08/22/spark-submit-in-java/
   so that you could add an extra env variables, etc.
   Later Spark made the Yarn client private to the spark package (~ the end of 2014). So if to name your package org.apache.spark - is possibly an option..
2. The built on top of spark-submit solution (with its advantages and drawbacks) is described here:
   http://www.henningpetersen.com/post/22/running-apache-spark-jobs-from-applications

> > What about **SparkR.R,** it uses spark-sumbit internally : 
> >     https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/R/pkg/R/sparkR.R
> >     when it call **launchBackend()** from https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/R/pkg/R/client.R 
> >     and give there all environment set already + arguments

Comment: Thank you, I didn't expect this to be so cumbersome. Have you also tried using spark in application on mesos? Would it be easier since we provide the mesos master address port explicitly to spark?

Comment: Sorry, haven't had a chance to check on Mesos